# How to make ID as variable and use it in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I have this code. It's actually a test. I want to use the variable hoveredColor to create a function changing the "this" div's background. But i can't seem to make it work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentcolor = "red";
  var hovercolor="";
  var hoveredColor = "";
  setColor();
  $("#settings div").hover(function(){
    hoveredColor = $(this).attr('id');
  }); 

  $("#black").hover(function(){
    hovercolor = $("#black").attr("id");
    document.getElementById('this').style.backgroundColor=hovercolor;
  },function(){
    document.getElementById('this').style.backgroundColor=currentcolor;
  });
  $("#"+hoveredColor).click(function(){ 
    currentcolor = $("#"+hoveredColor).attr('id');
    setColor();
  });

</script>

<div style="display: none;width:100%;" id="settings">
    <div style="width: 50px;height:50px; background-color: blue; float: left;display: block;margin-left: 10px" id="blue"> ff </div>
    <div style="width: 50px;height:50px; background-color: black; float: left;display: block;margin-left: 10px" id="black"> Black </div>
    <div style="width: 50px;height:50px; background-color: pink; float: left;display: block;margin-left: 10px" id="pink"> Pink </div>
</div>


<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;margin-top: 75px;" id="this">
    <p>I hope this works.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: At the moment you are trying to bind the `click` event handler, `hoverColor` is still an empty string. The assignment `hoveredColor = $(this).attr('id');` only takes place when the corresponding have been hovered over, which is a looooong time after `<script>` element was evaluated. Add some `console.log` statements to learn how exactly the code is executed.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to make this work? Actually i can make this work if i directly use the id of the hovered div. But that would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have improved your script a little, and here is what I have done:

1. Declare a global colour called `currentcolor`, as your code has shown, so that the `#this` div reverts to red background when the mouse leaves the child `<div>` in `#settings`.
2. Declare a global variable called `fixcolor`. This will let us know if the user has clicked on a div to set/fix the color, which we will update it later so that this does not interfere with the mouse leave event.

Distilling all that information above, here is the jQuery code (and [view the demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2zLn3a90/)):

```
$(function() {
    // Define global variables
    var currentcolor = 'red',
        fixcolor = false;

    $('#settings div').hover(function() {
        // Mouseover
        $('#this').css('background-color', $(this).attr('id'));
    }, function() {
        // Mouseout
        if(!fixcolor) $('#this').css('background-color', currentcolor);
    }).click(function() {
        // Bind click
        $('#this').css('background-color', $(this).attr('id'));
        fixcolor = true;
    });
});
```

---

However, here are some suggestions:

1. **Store the colour not in the ID, but as a HTML5 `data-` attribute**. This allows you to change the color of the divs without needing to update the ID and its selectors in your stylesheet, if any.
2. **Unhide the `#settings`**. I don't see a point in hiding, as it simply renders the script unusable since all the divs are hidden from the user, anyway.

To use the `data-` attribute, replace `id` with a name of your choice, say `data-bgcolor`:

```
<div style="width:100%;" id="settings">
    <div style="..." data-bgcolor="blue"> ff </div>
    <!-- MORE -->
</div>
```

And the value in this attribute can be accessed by either using `$(this).data('bgcolor')` or `$(this).attr('data-bgcolor')`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your JavaScript code so tightly depends on the format of your HTML markup, it might be a good idea to handle creating that HTML inside of your JavaScript. If you need to make changes to this little 'component' of your page, you can do it in one location (the .js) instead of having to make changes in your HTML and JavaScript.

Here's what the might look like.

```js
var DEFAULT_COLOR = 'red',
    COLOR_OPTIONS = [
        { 'text': 'Blue',  'color': 'blue' },
        { 'text': 'Black', 'color': 'black' },
        { 'text': 'Pink',  'color': 'pink' },
    ],
    COLOR_OPTION_TEMPLATE = '<div class="color-option" data-color="{{color}}" style="background-color: {{color}};">{{text}}</div>',
    settings_div = $('#settings'),
    bg_change_div = $('#this'),
    color_options_html = '',
    color_option_html = '';
        
function setBgColor(ele, color) {
    $(ele).css('background-color', color);
}
    
// Build HTML for the color-options divs.
$.each(COLOR_OPTIONS, function(i, color_option) {
    color_option_html = COLOR_OPTION_TEMPLATE.replace(/{{color}}/g, color_option.color);
    color_option_html = color_option_html.replace(/{{text}}/, color_option.text);
    color_options_html += color_option_html;
});
    
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // add color-options HTML to #settings
    settings_div.html(color_options_html);  
    // set default background-color for #this
    setBgColor(bg_change_div, DEFAULT_COLOR);
    
    settings_div.on('mouseenter', '.color-option', function(e) {
        setBgColor(bg_change_div, $(e.currentTarget).data('color'));
    });

    settings_div.on('mouseleave', '.color-option', function() {
        setBgColor(bg_change_div, DEFAULT_COLOR);
    });
});
```

```css
.color-option {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="settings">
  <!-- HTML will be added here via .js -->
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;margin-top: 75px;" id="this">
  <p>I hope this works.</p>
</div>
```